# How to stop Submit upon Enter Press ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I have created a form in Blazor.  The form is for entry of new records.

During user testing, they became frustrated because accidentally pressing the ENTER button will cause the form to post back.  IF validation fails, that is not an issue. BUT . . in the event that validation was success - it will post the incomplete record and refresh the page.I don't want that to happen.  I only want to post back when the submit button is pressed.

The form has 10 entry fields.
2 entry fields are required.

IF user enters both required fields and accidentally hits ENTER, the record submits and refreshes the page.

I understand that this is native ASP Behavior.

I have tried to add 'onkeydown:preventDefault="true"' on each text element.  That does indeed prevent Submit upon Enter press. But it also locks all my text boxes and does not allow data entry, which is needed for create new record.

```
<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=@WIR40Entity.VictimPhoneNumber @onkeydown:preventDefault="true" Placeholder=@ADphone MaxLength="15" class="w-100" />
```

Is there a simple way to stop this ?

Comment: Post your complete form, I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Use this: `$('input').keypress(function (e) { return e.keyCode !== 13; });`. It blocks enters in input fields.

Comment: @VDWWD - Thank you for this example.  I am not much familiar with Jscript.  Where do I place this within my Textbox>?  Not sure how to add code to the html in blazor.

Comment: You can put in on the page itself in a <script> tag, but usually you would have a .js script file for the site and you can put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to stop this ?

Yes.

Here's a demo page with no JS in sight.  It works on the fact that the `KeyDown` event gets fired before the form submit.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=_model OnSubmit=this.OnSubmit @onkeydown=this.OnEnter>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value=_model.Value />
    </div>
    <div class="text-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    </div>
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>Submit Accepted: @_submitAccepted</pre>
</div>


@code {
    private Model _model = new();
    private bool _submittedOnEnter;
    private bool _submitAccepted;

    private Task OnSubmit()
    {
        _submitAccepted = false;
        if (_submittedOnEnter)
        {
            _submittedOnEnter = false;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        _submitAccepted = true;
        // Do your stuff
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }

    private void OnEnter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter")
            _submittedOnEnter = true;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```